# OpenCms and MySQL configation: max_alllowed_packed

Tags: java, mysql, opencms

I have installed OpenCms on my local machine and it works perfectly fine.
But in order to work it correctly it is mentioned that i have to modify the `my.ini` file and set `max_alllowed_packed site to 32`
I have done it and it works perfectly fine.

But can I modify this file if I use a third party hosting provider for Tomcat and MySql?

Comment: You'd have to ask the provider ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to your server and access to the my.ini file with the correct permissions to it, then you can modify it. Otherwise you will need to check with your provider and ask them to do it for you.